# how to get the payment with ethermine.org

Tags: mining, payments

I am using ethermine to mine the ethereum for the experiment, now I setting the payment threshold to 0.08, now it comes to the threshold, and in the payout page, I got a payout which says the block_from, the block_to, amount and tx. I clicked the tx 's hyperlink, it is redirected to http://etherchain.org page with the transaction id, from the page I could see the eth address is my mining id, how could I transfer this eth to my personal wallet, because right now I don't know the private key for the mining address

Comment: You may need to wait for payment round, if that won't help I would contact them. Payment rounds depending on pool can be anywhere between in 30 minutes to in 24h. I would worry after 24h.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this link helps: https://ethpool.freshdesk.com/support/solutions/articles/8000045848-i-have-not-received-my-payment

Thank you

Comment: Hi there. Can you summarise the content of the link, and how it applies to the original question? Currently, if the link goes dead, then your answer becomes obsolete, which is why link-only answers are discouraged: [Are answers that just contain links elsewhere really “good answers”?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers). Also see the guidelines in this site's Help Centre on  [Answering Questions](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer).